# command line loop through all folders and execute command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to create a windows batch file "compile.bat" that loops through all subfolders inside "workspace" exept for the folter ".metadata", and execute "mvn clean install" in there. I would also like it to find the file with the ".jar" extension (the only file in the map "target" inside that folder) and force copy it to a fixed directory. so if my map structure is like this:

```
-eclipse
-maven
-some other folders and files
-compile.bat
-workspace
  -.metadata
  -someFolder
   -target
    -randomFolders
    *someName.jar
  -someOtherFolder
   -target
    -moreRandomFolders
    *someOtherName.jar
```

it would have to do:

```
cd workspace
cd someFolder
mvn clean install
::copy someName.jar to fixed map
cd ..
cd someOtherFolder
mvn clean install
::copy someNameOther.jar to fixed map
cd ..
```

How to do this?

EDIT: here's what I ended up using:

```
for /F %%p in ('dir /ad /b workspace') do (
  echo.%%p | findstr /I "metadata" 1>nul
  if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Whatever, I can do what I want %%p
    cd workspace/%%p
    mvn clean install
    cd target
    for /r %%i in (*.jar) do (
      echo %%i
      copy "%%i" "../../../CraftBukkit/target/plugins" /Y
    )
    cd ../../..
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
for /F %%p in ('dir /ad /b workspace') do (
  echo.%%p | findstr /I "metadata" 1>nul
  if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Whatever, I can do what I want %%p
    cd %%p
    mvn clean install
    cd ..
  )
)
```

Comment: I tried it, and after a slight modification it works. what I changed: `cd %%p` to `cd workspace/%%p` and `cd ..` to `cd ../..` however I have updated the OP with another question